# Flutter: Displaying Images List from Device Gallery

Tags: image, listview, flutter, dart

I have ListView for photos and I am trying to get photos from gallery and display them on the screen, but the problem is when I press to add a new photo the whole photos change to the new photo.

I want to change every photo separately without changing the other photos.

```
File _image;
final picker = ImagePicker();

Future getImage() async {
  final image = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  setState(() {
    _image = File(image.path);
    print((image.path));
  });
}

 child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: 1,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
      return Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              getImage();

            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:5.0, right:5,top: 10),
              child: Container(
                height: 100.0,
                width: 100.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: _image == null ? AssetImage(
                        'assets/images/add_pic.jpg') : FileImage(_image),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

start with this code :

```
List<File> _images = [];
final picker = ImagePicker();

Future getImage(int index) async {
  final image = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  setState(() {
    _images[index] = File(image.path);
    print((image.path));
  });
}

 child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: _images.length + 1,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
      if(index == _images.length){
        return GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              getImage(index);
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:5.0, right:5,top: 10),
              child: Container(
                height: 100.0,
                width: 100.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/add_pic.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
         );
      }
      return Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              getImage();
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:5.0, right:5,top: 10),
              child: Container(
                height: 100.0,
                width: 100.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: FileImage(_image[index]),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Did it work with you? because I received this error when I applied it : error: The element type 'Set<GestureDetector>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.

Comment: do you use any `Set` in your code? and may you share the full error?

Comment: There is not Set in code, and this is the full error followed by these errors : error: Unexpected text 'return'. (unexpected_token at [hpxksa] lib/Screens/ad_images_scroll_view.dart:46)
error: Undefined name '_image'. (undefined_identifier at [hpxksa] lib/Screens/ad_images_scroll_view.dart:58)
error: Undefined name '_image'. (undefined_identifier at [hpxksa] lib/Screens/ad_images_scroll_view.dart:59)
error: Expected to find '}'. (expected_token at [hpxksa] lib/Screens/ad_images_scroll_view.dart:66)
error: 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.

Comment: just follow the line numbers (46, 58, 59 and 66) in the errors and resolve them; one of them is to replace the line `image: FileImage(_image[index]),` with `image: FileImage(_images[index]),` the difference is 's' ... and so on

Comment: that's because I wrote the code in a browser, not in an IDE

Comment: I corrected all the bugs and left with these : error: The element type 'Set<GestureDetector>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. (list_element_type_not_assignable at [hpxksa] lib/Screens/ad_images_scroll_view.dart:40)
error: Unexpected text 'return'. (unexpected_token at [hpxksa] lib/Screens/ad_images_scroll_view.dart:41)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216285/discussion-between-muhammad-adam-and-alex-ali).